# Is a method that is writing to a logger pure?

Tags: c#, attributes

A pure method is defined as "[does not make any visible state changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx)".

My method is writing a log message if one argument is null or an exception is thrown. Is it still pure? Is writing to a logger a visible change?

Here's the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Formats with invariant culture - won't throw an exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="format">A composite format string.</param>
    /// <param name="args">An object array that contains zero or more objects to format.</param>
    /// <returns>A copy of format in which the format items have been replaced by the string representation of the corresponding objects in args.</returns>
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters", MessageId = "CyanCor.Core.Logging.Log.ExceptionPrevent(System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.String)", Justification = "It is for the logger (riedl)")]
    [Pure - yes or no?]
    public static string FormatSafe(this string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (format == null)
        {
            Log.ExceptionPrevent("Argument format is null");
            return NullFormat;
        }

        try
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException exc)
        {
            Log.Exception(exc);
            return format;
        }
        catch (FormatException exc)
        {
            Log.Exception(exc);
            return format;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why declare it pure? Do you want to call it from a contract?

Comment: Well, you could argue it's a pure function that yields to an impure function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, "state change" means modifying the state of an object, ie. modifying a variable or changing the structure of a complex object. Following this definition, it would seem that your method is still pure.

Comment: By that definition changing a value in a database could still be considered "pure" which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @tster Consider that the database is a "complex object", then we are making a change to its state == state change. Then the question is "is the state change visible," which most likely it is considering it is changing the state of an external data store.

Comment: I think in the end it's subjective.  While I agree that this method is probably pure, there are contexts where it would not be.  For example, if you are processing your log files (for example, to calculate charges), then the log file itself would be a "complex object" as well.